# showing column data as header in telerik radgrid

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

```
I have a table in dataset like:

-------------------
id  class name      sub 
------------------------
1   mca   aditya    network
2   mca   abhishek  daa
3   mca   akhilesh  algorithm
4   btech ram       cs
5   btech shyam     ds
6   btech anand     client/server
7   mba   furqan    os
8   mba   arvind    marketing
9   mba   aayush    hr

I want a result set in telerik rad grid like the following:

----------------
class    name      sub
------------------------
mca      aditya    network
         abhishek  daa
         akhilesh  algorithm
btech    ram       cs
         shyam     ds
         anand     client/server
mba      furqan    os
         arvind    marketing
         aayush    hr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John DeVight has written an [extension](http://www.aspnetwiki.com/page%3aextending-the-telerik-mvc-client-api) to the Telerik MVC grid. He has a function called hideGroupColumns that hides columns that are grouped. The syntax looks like this:

```
$('#grid').data('tGrid').hideGroupColumns()
```

The Telerik community forums has [some discussion](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/hide-column-when-grid-is-grouped-by-that-column.aspx) of this extension.